# Use a vector name as a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know I can use a vector name as a pointer. For example, if I want to see the contents of an array using this technique, I can do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 5

int main(void) {
    int *p;
    int a[MAX] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for(p = a; p < a + MAX; p++)
        printf("%d -> (%p)\n", *p, p);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I want to do the same thing with a two-dimensional vector using the same technique (since a two-dimensional vector in C is processed as a single-dimensional vector), and I thought I'd do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 5

int main(void) {
    int *p;
    int b[MAX][MAX] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
        {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
        {16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
        {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}
    };

    for(p = b; p < b + MAX * 2; p++)
        printf("%d -> (%p)\n", *p, p);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

but it does not work. I could write:

```
for(p = &b[0][0]; p <= &b[MAX - 1][MAX - 1]; p++)
        printf("%d -> (%p)\n", *p, p);
```

but I'd like to understand why I can't use syntax like the one used for the one-dimensional vector.

Comment: How many elements are there in a matrix of r rows and c columns?

Comment: `printf("%d -> (%p)\n", *p, (void *)p);` Please ensure the cast. Why not 2 running pointers in nested loops? Using just one pointer in single loop is too much assumption.

Comment: Gyapti Jain, because I read in my book that a two-dimensional array is seen as a one-dimensional array, and since the addresses associated with the content are adjacent, it makes me think that I can use a single 'for' loop by using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: And BTW; "*it does not work.*" is the more less worst trouble report, error description one can give. Please be more precise telling us what you'd expected **and** what you observe.

Comment: *If* going this route then `MAX * 2` ought to be `MAX * MAX`. Alonf with casting `b` to `int*`.

Comment: Alk, using this for as suggested to me by others "for (p = b; p <b + MAX; p ++)", gives me warnings using gcc: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int *' from 'int [5] [5]'
       [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
among other things in the expression p <b + MAX would be more logical a "p <b + MAX * MAX"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the name of an array (there are no "vectors" in C), it "decays" into a pointer to the array's first element.  That's simple and clear for simple (1D) arrays, but when you move to "2D" arrays, things are more complicated.  First of all, the term "2D array" is ambiguous in C -- there are arrays of arrays and arrays of pointers, either of which can act like a 2D array, but they are very different.

In your case, you have an array of arrays, so you can do something like:

```
int b[MAX][MAX] = ...
int (*p1)[MAX];
int *p2;

for (p1 = b; p1 < b + MAX; p1++)
    for (p2 = *p1; p2 < *p1 + MAX; p2++)
        printf("%d -> (%p)\n", *p2, p2);
```

here, you use `p1` to iterate over the outer array (so `p1` is a pointer to an array), and then use `p2` to iterate over each array.

If you really want to do it as a single loop, you can do

```
int *p;
for (p = *b; p < *(b + MAX); p++)
    printf("%d -> (%p)\n", *p, p);
```

Comment: I like how you did it in a single loop, but as I understand it, the correct form would be to do it in two loop, but unfortunately I have warnings and more precisely (I use gcc):warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int *'
      from 'int [5][5]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Comment: @RobertoRocco: you need to change the declaration of `p1` as I have done here.  Either example I have compiles with no warnings.